# Yii - HTML options to make HTML tags visible

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

Now I'm using the combobox extension to create a dropdownlist. Below is the code generated using dropdownlist.

```
<select id="SearchForm_min_cost_select" style="display: none;">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="10 lakhs">10 lakhs</option>
<option value="20 lakhs">20 lakhs</option>
<option value="30 lakhs">30 lakhs</option>
<option value="40 lakhs">40 lakhs</option>
<option value="50 lakhs">50 lakhs</option>
<option value="60 lakhs">60 lakhs</option>
<option value="70 lakhs">70 lakhs</option>
<option value="80 lakhs">80 lakhs</option>
<option value="90 lakhs">90 lakhs</option>
<option value="1 crores">1 crores</option>
<option value="2 crores">2 crores</option>
<option value="3 crores">3 crores</option>
<option value="4 crores">4 crores</option>
<option value="5 crores">5 crores</option>
</select>
```

The default style property is `display:none` and currently not visible. How can I make it visible using html options.
Below is the code of dropdown created using widget :

```
<?php        
                $this->widget('ext.combobox.EJuiComboBox', array(
                    'model' => $model,
                    'attribute' => 'min',
                    // data to populate the select. Must be an array.
                    'data' =>Yii::app()->params['data'],
                    // options passed to plugin
                    'options' => array(                                  
                        'allowText' => false,                       
                    ),
                    // Options passed to the text input                   
                    'htmlOptions' => array('placeholder' => 'Min', 'style'=>'width:70px'),
                ));

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'style'=>'width:70px;display:block'
```